# Complementary Transmission Gate Circuit

Tags: vlsi, high-impedance

Here is the circuit.

[image]

Now what would be the voltages at Node Y on the positive edge of the clock, if Switching Time from on to off and off to on of Transmission Gates are : 0.5ns, 1ns, 2ns

Comment: This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Dave Tweed : This is not any homework question. I was confused in a bigger circuit, but here I have shown only required portion. I am facing trouble in the situation, in which suppose one TG is off (providing high impedance) and 2nd TG either requires some time to fully turn on or currently in off state, so what would be the voltage on node Y?

Comment: Nonetheless, my comment is still valid. The question as posed is too broad -- you need to narrow it down to a specific issue that you feel confused about. Also, you need to tell us something about yourself, either here or in your profile, so that we can tailor an answer to your level of skill and experience.

Comment: @Dave Tweed : I am an Electronics Engineer. Now in the above circuit, considering all parameters as described in the question, I am confused, when TG1 is off (So High-Z) and TG2 is is not yet fully on (so may be it is in the process of switching from off to on or it is currently off), then what would appear at node Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the input to a CMOS gate represents a significant capacitance that stores charge. You can think of it as a capacitor connected to ground.

When TG1 is on (and TG2 is off), node Y charges to the same voltage as X. When TG1 turns off, node Y simply keeps this same voltage, since the charge has nowhere to go, except for leakage paths that might cause the voltage to droop slightly.

The two inverters drive the voltage on the bottom end of TG2 to nominally the same value as node Y (and node X). So, when TG2 turns on, there is no appreciable change in the voltage at node Y, other than that any "droop" gets eliminated — assuming that the voltage didn't droop so far as to cause the voltage at node Z to change.

Comment: Yup it essentially behaves like a cap & so it will retain it's value for a while. Thanks for the answer.